# How to convert string to ISOString?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have 3 variables: (1)Date (2) StartTime (3) EndTime
I would like to bring them as two variables (1)Date and StartTime (2) Date and EndTime, so that I can create a google calendar event.

As per my understanding, in order to create a google calendar event I need to pass ISO String format for event timings. Can anyone check the below code and help me with the missing piece.

```
 function createEvent(title,Dt,startTime,endTime,col) {
 var calendarId = '_____@group.calendar.google.com';
 Logger.log(Dt); //2016-07-21
 Logger.log(startTime); // 11:55 AM
 Logger.log(typeof(startTime)); //string


 //Help Needed to convert + to ISO

 var event = {
 summary: title,
 start: {
 dateTime: startISO
 },
 end: {
 dateTime: endISO
 },
 colorId: col
 };
 event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
 Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```

Comment: you can get ISO by following three steps, 1) Convert your time from am/pm to 24 hours as 11:55 AM = 11:55 and 11:55 PM = 23:55, 2) then concatenate both date and time with space like 2016-07-21 11:55 and then 3) get date from string as var date = new Date("2016-07-21 11:55"); which will be ISO date

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.toISOString()` on the `Date` object to get an ISO String, but Google Calendar is requesting a slightly different format than this, but it is a quick fix. Start with a normal conversion:

```
(new Date()).toISOString(); // "2016-07-29T00:00:00.000Z"

var startTime = new Date();
var isoStartTime = startTime.toISOString();
```

If you need to make the `Date` from separate objects you can:

```
var yourDate = '2016-07-29';
var yourTime = '11:55 AM';

var startTime = new Date(yourDate);
startTime.setHours(yourTime.split(':')[0]); // 11
startTime.setMinutes(yourTime.split(':')[1].substr(0,2)); // 55

startTime = startTime.toISOString(); // "2016-07-29T11:55:00.000Z"
```

Then change it to what Google's looking for:

```
// To RFC 3339...
startTime.substr(0,startTime.length-5)+'Z'; // "2016-07-29T11:55:00Z"
```

Or

```
//if the "startTime = startTime.toISOString()" assignment happened
startTime.split('.')[0]+'Z';

//if startTime is a Date object, not a string
startTime.toISOString().split('.')[0]+'Z';
```

You can also (and probably preferrably) use numbers instead of strings for all that; if you pass `hours` and `minutes` separately it could look cleaner than that string operation:

```
var startTime = new Date(yourDate);
startTime.setHours(yourHours); // string or int
startTime.setMinutes(yourMinutes); // string or int
```

Comment: It didn't work. 
function Test1() {
  
  var yourDate = '2016-07-29';
  Logger.log(yourDate);

  var yourTime = '11:55 AM';
  Logger.log(yourTime);  

  var startTime = new Date(yourDate);
  Logger.log(startTime);

  startTime.setHours(yourTime.split(':')[0]); // 11
  Logger.log(startTime);

  startTime.setMinutes(yourTime.split(':')[1].substr(0,2)); // 55
  Logger.log(startTime);

  startTime.toISOString();
  Logger.log(startTime);  

}

**Error:**
 RangeError: Date is invalid. (line 18, file "Test1")

**Log Output:**
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 GMT-08:00 1969

Comment: Looks like the RFC3339 has a character fewer: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339
What I've written above has `...000Z`, but their docs (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) are asking for RFC3339 which shows `...00Z`